# Is there a statistical test to determine correlation between the first derivative of two time based series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, cross-correlation, derivative

I have two time series. They are normally distributed, parametric, exactly the same size and evenly spaced.

I am seeking to determine if the rate of change of these two time series are correlated with each other.

Looking at other posts about correlation of time series on this forum, tests like cross-correlation and ARIMA are good tools to evaluate if two time series are correlated; but I have found nothing about correlating their derivatives. Is there any particular tests for this task? Or should I just take the derivates and run a cross correlation on them.

Any other primers on correlating time series would be appreciated; as I don't have much experience on the subject.

Thank you!

Comment: ARIMA is a model for a single time series, hence incapable of bivariate analysis.